# Team Foundation Backup Plan failure message

Tags: team-foundation-server

I ran my backup and it failed due to timeout. The message I see is:

> ```
> The SQL Server timeout value is set to 6 hours. This value can be modified in the tool's setting file
> ```

Does anyone know which tool and which file this message is referring to?

Answer (score 0):

After ransacking my system I found the file ConfigPT.xml contains a SqlStatementTimeoutInSeconds setting. There are two versions of this file that appear to need changing.